# Not able to auto fill checkbox and select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table and some input fields inside my form
what I am doing is

- When I click  on any row of my HTML table I am retrieving their values back to the input field
- the input fields values are easily refilling but the select dropdown and checkbox are not refilling
- on clicking on table rows I want to `checked` the checkbox if it is `y`
- And same as for select, want to retrieve the text of the row which it is assigned to

**snippet**

```js
var data = [{
    "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "admin",
    "User LoginId": "admin",
    "User Password": "admin",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "maiyas",
    "User LoginId": "maiyas",
    "User Password": "maiyas",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
    "User Name": "cbadmin",
    "User LoginId": "cbadmin",
    "User Password": "cbadmin",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "CHEF BAKERS",
    "User Name": "cbaker",
    "User LoginId": "cbaker",
    "User Password": "cbaker",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "JAYANAGAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "jayanagar",
    "User LoginId": "jayanagar",
    "User Password": "jayanagar",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "MALLESHWARAM MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "malleswaram",
    "User LoginId": "malleswaram",
    "User Password": "malleswaram",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  },
  {
    "Distributor Name": "KOLAR MAIYAS RESTAURANTS PVT LTD",
    "User Name": "kolar",
    "User LoginId": "kolar",
    "User Password": "kolar",
    "User role": "DISTRIBUTOR",
    "Active": "Y"
  }
]
var columndef = [{
    title: "Distributor Name",
    data: "Distributor Name"
  }, {
    title: "User Name",
    data: "User Name"
  }, {
    title: "User LoginId",
    data: "User LoginId"
  },
  {
    title: "User Password",
    data: "User Password"
  },
  {
    title: "User role",
    data: "User role"
  },
  {
    title: "Active",
    data: "Active"
  }
]
$('#tble').DataTable({
  columns: columndef,
  "columnDefs": [{
    "className": "dt-left",
    "targets": "_all"
  }],
  data: data,
  scrollY: "30vh",
  responsive: true,
  "bInfo": false,
  paging: false,
  scrollX: "100%",
  scrollCollapse: true
});

(function() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', run, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', run);
  }

  function run() {
    var t = document.getElementById('tble');
    t.onclick = function(event) {
      event = event || window.event; //IE8
      var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
      while (target && target.nodeName != 'TR') { // find TR
        target = target.parentElement;
      }
      //if (!target) { return; } //tr should be always found
      var cells = target.cells; //cell collection - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement
      //var cells = target.getElementsByTagName('td'); //alternative
      if (!cells.length || target.parentNode.nodeName == 'THEAD') {
        return;
      }
      var f1 = document.getElementById('distributorName');
      var f2 = document.getElementById('userCode');
      var f3 = document.getElementById('userName');
      var f4 = document.getElementById('loginId');
      var f5 = document.getElementById('password');
      var f6 = document.getElementById('active');
      f1.value = cells[0].innerHTML;
      f2.value = cells[1].innerHTML;
      f3.value = cells[2].innerHTML;
      f4.value = cells[3].innerHTML;
      f5.value = cells[4].innerHTML;
      f6.value = cells[5].innerHTML;
      //console.log(target.nodeName, event);
    };
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/sc-1.5.0/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/r-2.2.2/sc-1.5.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
<div class="container form-group" id="container-userAdmin">
  <form id="changePasswordForm">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="distributorName" id="commonHeader">Distributor
      Name:</label>
        <select id="distributorName" class="form-control test">

        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="userCode" id="commonHeader">User Code:</label> <input type="text" id="userCode" name="usercode" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="user Code" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="userName" id="commonHeader">Name of the User:</label> <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="User Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="loginId" id="commonHeader">login Id:</label> <input type="text" id="loginId" name="loginid" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="Login Id">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="confirm_password" id="commonHeader"> Password:</label> <input type="text" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control commonClass" required="required">
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="checkbox" id="commonHeader">Active </label> <input type="checkbox" id="active" class="d-block">

      </div>

    </div>
    <hr>



    <table id="tble" class="table-striped table-bordered table-hover " style="width: 100%!important;"></table>
    <br>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">
     <i class="fa fa-save"></i>save
    </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You can write `if(cells[5].innerHTML == 'Y'){
            f6.checked = true;
          }` for checkbox.

Comment: @SudhirOjha and what for select `dropdown` can you help me with some running code? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkbox doesn't contains property value  you can use following code:

```
var f6 = document.getElementById('active');
if(cells[5].innerHTML=='Y')
{
    f6.checked=true;
}
else
{
    f6.checked=false;
}
```

I am supposing that you are storing 'Y' for check and 'N' for uncheck checkbox values in your data table.

Comment: This will not work because `cells[5].innerHTML` will give you `Y`

Comment: and what should i do for select tag

Comment: Yes it can be anything, one can replace 'checked' with 'Y' that will work fine. As i have written this is my supposition

Comment: var f6 = document.getElementById('dropdown');
f6.value="yourvalue";
This will work for drop down

Comment: @ShahMuhammadTalha that checked worked,but not dropdown

Comment: Please check in your attached html code drop down select donot have options please add options in it. If the value of js will match any of the option value then it will be selected as default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188000/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-shah-muhammad-talha).